# Error Message for MDFileManager with preview

Tags: python, kivy

I try to run the ready code in Kivy cite about MDFileManager component:
https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/file-manager/index.html

However I obtain an error message due to this line "preview=True,"

`line 36, in __init__preview=True,`

Because when I delete it, I can run the code without any error. But this result is not enough for me. I need to display all images in a path as a list.

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.filemanager import MDFileManager
from kivymd.toast import toast


KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        title: "MDFileManager"
        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: None]]
        elevation: 10

    FloatLayout:

        MDRoundFlatIconButton:
            text: "Open manager"
            icon: "folder"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .6}
            on_release: app.file_manager_open()
'''


class Example(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.events)
        self.manager_open = False
        self.file_manager = MDFileManager(
            exit_manager=self.exit_manager,
            select_path=self.select_path,
            preview=True,
        )

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def file_manager_open(self):
        self.file_manager.show('/')  # output manager to the screen
        self.manager_open = True

    def select_path(self, path):
        '''It will be called when you click on the file name
        or the catalog selection button.

        :type path: str;
        :param path: path to the selected directory or file;
        '''

        self.exit_manager()
        toast(path)

    def exit_manager(self, *args):
        '''Called when the user reaches the root of the directory tree.'''

        self.manager_open = False
        self.file_manager.close()

    def events(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        '''Called when buttons are pressed on the mobile device.'''

        if keyboard in (1001, 27):
            if self.manager_open:
                self.file_manager.back()
        return True


Example().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to eliminate this error is to update to kivy 2.0. Another way is to move the `preview` into the `kv`:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        title: "MDFileManager"
        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: None]]
        elevation: 10

    FloatLayout:

        MDRoundFlatIconButton:
            text: "Open manager"
            icon: "folder"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .6}
            on_release: app.file_manager_open()
            
<MDFileManager>:
    preview: True
```

and remove it from the python:

```
class Example(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.events)
        self.manager_open = False
        self.file_manager = MDFileManager(
            exit_manager=self.exit_manager,
            select_path=self.select_path
        )
```

Comment: Thank you.
Even with this solution, I don't obtain a list of pictures as describe in KivyMD website
https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/file-manager/index.html

I obtain only the title of image without pictures

Comment: Thank you so much,

Best solution is to upgrade to 2.0 version.